# blender edge crease Invalid

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

[image]
He doesn't work when I use subdivisions

This is the uploaded file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rKluT2TomDGfA4u_UMgL3OPLji65zgjx

Answer (score 1):

you need to crease this edge as well:

[image]

Comment: Okay Thank you for your help :D